# Abstracting/restricting calls to back end API that is exposed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Working on a simple HTML application that makes calls to an API using jQuery. Would like to avoid someone getting the API address (via looking at the source and/or network traffic) and making calls directly to the API without the HTML pages getting loaded first. Thinking about adding a header or cookie that the API can validate to ensure this request is coming from the Javascript embedded in that page, and not someone calling the API direct. However, even this could be replicated by someone looking to talk to the API directly. Would like to keep this a simple HTML project as much as possible (realize creating a Node.js version of the application, or using Thymeleaf in Spring Boot would give more options to obscure the API). It feels like this is a limitation of doing an HTML/Javscript solution. But, maybe we are missing something obvious. Any tips?

Comment: If the user has access to the API, then what exactly are you trying to restrict?  Why does it matter to the server if the request came from your client-side code or theirs?

Comment: The site makes money through advertising (which is served in the HTML)